# How to get anatytics per user per api version in wso2?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-das

I have configured WSO2 DAS & API manager. I need per user / api version stats. As per documentation there is direct navigation for per user stats which I am not able to find. Could you please help me to configure it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When the API is created, API level usage can be seen based on Version and users. Screenshot is available at https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Viewing+API+Statistics under “API Publisher statistics”

Comment: Its not there in navigation. Its only there in document/ link shared by you

Comment: Looks like it was in an older version and has been removed in 1.10.0 release. But the doc has not been updated properly.